# If $G$ is an acyclic graph, then $G$ has a source

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm hoping for some feedback on this graph theoretic proof -- my main issue with it is the inductive step, which seems to show that if $G$ has a cyclic subgraph, then $G$ is cylic, which is not quite what I want to show here.

**Theorem**

If $G$ is an acyclic graph, then $G$ has a source (namely, a vertex with no inbound edges).

**Proof**

We show the contrapositive: if G has no source, then $G$ is not acyclic ($G$ is cyclic).

By hypothesis $G$ has no source, so each node has at least one inbound edge. If $G$ has two nodes, $a$ and $b$, both $a$ and $b$ have inbound edges $ab$ and $ba$ respectively. Hence $G$ is not acyclic.

Otherwise, assume $G$ is a graph with $k$ nodes $g_1, g_2, ..., g_k$, cycles $\eta_1, \eta_2, ..., \eta_p$, and that each node has at least one inbound edge.

Now take $G$, a graph with $n+1$ nodes such that $G$ is a subgraph of $G'$ and each node has at least one inbound edge. Since $G$ is a subgraph of $G'$, $G'$ must also be cyclic, since the edge and node sets of $G$ are subsets of $G'$.

Then we have shown by induction that if G has no source, then $G$ is not acyclic.

Comment: If $G$ is a subgraph of $G'$ it does not follow that they have the same vertices, or that $G'$ must be cyclic. Do you mean $G'$ has $n$ vertices and is a subgraph of $G$? An alternative proof is to use induction as follows: Suppose it is true for $n$ vertices. Take a vertex $v$ with an inbound edge; remove it; the remaining graph has a source, by induction; this vertex remains a source when $v$ is reinserted otherwise a cycle is produced.

Comment: beautiful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative proof: Take an arbitrary node in an acyclic graph. If it's a source, you're done. If not, follow an arbitrary inbound edge backwards to a neighbor node. Repeat indefinitely.

It is impossible to get back to a node you've previously visited, because the graph is acyclic. Therefore, after some number of moves (at the latest after visiting each node), you must reach a point where you can't move any more. That's a source.

Comment: Let me know what your thoughts are on my most recent answer to this question -- I realize the proof I propose is more or less the same as yours so of course I'll keep your answer as the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

A formal version of the more intuitive proof proposed by @arthur

**Theorem**

Every acyclic graph has a source.

**Proof**

Suppose not -- suppose every vertex in every acyclic graph has at least one predecessor.

Let $G$ be a finite, acyclic graph. Choose $v_k \in V(G)$, $k \in \mathcal{I}$, with $\mathcal{I}$ an index set over $v_k$ and its predecessors.

By hypothesis, every $v \in V(G)$ has a predecessor, so regardless of our choice of $k$, there exists some $k - 1 \in \mathcal{I}$. Then we can inductively choose predecessors of $v_{k-1}, v_{k - 2}, ...$, and so on.

But $G$ is finite, so it must be that there exist $m, n \in \mathcal{I}$ such that $m < n$ and $v_m = v_n$. Then we have exhibited a cycle with $v_m ... v_n$, contradicting our assumption that $G$ had no source. Since $G$ was arbitrary, it must be that every acyclic graph has a source. $\square$